# wget to https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola error connection time out

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, user-interface

I have the following errors when I try to wget in my box:

```
wget https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola
--2012-11-07 14:01:27--  https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola
Resolving graph.facebook.com... 69.171.234.22, 2a03:2880:10:8f01:face:b00c:0:26
Connecting to graph.facebook.com|69.171.234.22|:443... failed: Connection timed out
```

Whats wrong? Port https is open in my firewall.

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere   
state NEW tcp dpt:https
```

Can someone have solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It should work since it's just JSON returned and there is no access token needed

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola
```